# can not use geoserver rest API with geoserver-manager

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

I want to use rest API of geoserver with geoserver-manager plugin. In netbeans I create a new web application maven project:
[image]

then in pom.xml file in dependencies I add bellow dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>it.geosolutions</groupId>
     <artifactId>geoserver-manager</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.1</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

in index.jsp file I add bellow code:

```
<%@page import="it.geosolutions.geoserver.rest.GeoServerRESTReader"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            String RESTURL  = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/";
            String RESTUSER = "admin";
            String RESTPW   = "geoserver";

            GeoServerRESTReader reader = new GeoServerRESTReader(RESTURL, RESTUSER, RESTPW);
            //GeoServerRESTPublisher publisher = new GeoServerRESTPublisher(RESTURL, RESTUSER, RESTPW);
        %>

    </body>
</html>
```

but the result is: 
[image]

**Where is problem?**